# Do TortoiseCVS and TortoiseSVN conflict when simultaneously installed?

Tags: version-control, tortoisesvn, tortoisecvs

I am interested if it's safe to install both TortoiseCVS and TortoiseSVN on the same computer? All our corporate projects are controlled by CVS, but I want to use SVN for my personal documents (and TortoiseSVN as client). Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They both can be used together with no (ok, almost no) problems.
One problem you might experience is that some of the overlay icons won't show up anymore. This is because Windows has only about 12 slots available for overlay icons, and with both TortoiseSVN and TortoiseCVS installed, they together use more than the 12 available slots.

See this FAQ entry about this:
[The overlay icons appear, but not all of them!](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovlnotall)

However, TortoiseSVN has created a common overlay handler, which other Tortoise clients can use to avoid this very issue. TortoiseCVS now uses that common handler too, but that isn't included in the stable release yet. You'd have to use an unstable version from here:
http://testpilot.tortoisecvs.org/
Using TortoiseSVN 1.5.x and TortoiseCVS from the testpilot site will give you all the overlays for both SVN and CVS working copies.

Answer (score 4):

They can be used without any problem on the same machine. Even in the [same folders](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/105) if you want...

Answer (score 1):

I had both of it installed and met no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated tortoiseCVS and tortoise SVN
it theems not working (CVS icon overlay not diplayed) with these folowing versions 
I'm interressed in any other suggestion.

I'm orking under Windows XP pro SP3.

TortoiseCVS version
1.10.8 RC 11 plus test fixes built on Mon Aug 18 22:10:04 2008

TortoiseSVN 1.5.6, Build 14908 - 32 Bit , 2008/12/20 11:51:04
Subversion 1.5.5, 
apr 1.2.12
apr-utils 1.2.12
berkeley db 4.4.20
neon 0.28.3
OpenSSL 0.9.8i 15 Sep 2008
zlib 1.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Got mine working when reinstalled TortoiseCVS-1.10.10.exe and TortoiseSVN-1.6.2.16344-win32-svn-1.6.2. I have win x64 sp2 with latest updates and when i open explorer it shows only cvs folder icons but when i open explorer like so '%WinDir%\SysWow64\Explorer.exe /e, /separate' then it shows only svn folder icons, so it is possible on x64 also with some difficulties. I have had problems with both programs especially svn64bit version. Hope that helps XP x64 users.

Answer (score 0):

I have TortoiseCSV install and later installed TortoiseSVN I immediately started have window explorer crashes every time I tried to bring up right-click context menu. This even started to occur when right-clicking on desktop screen. Screen would go blank and then attempt to reload all taskbar applications. Uninstalling TortoiseSVN corrected the condition...no more crashes!

Answer (score 0):

On vista64, I have both installed (cvs:1.10.10, svn: 1.6.3) and smartcvs/svn. I have no problems except that icons overlay is arbitrarily buggy, but does not lead to crashes.